# spark taking a long time for reading a compressed json on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 compressed jsons files (bz2) on HDFS. I have to load them in Spark. For this, first I have started pyspark (shell) and then perform following queries for this:

```
>> df = spark.read.load("hdfs://master:9000/data/db1/file_part*.bz2", format="json", sep=",", inferSchema="true")
    [Stage 0:>                              (8 + 4) / 503]
```

As it can be seen that it is loading data. Why this is happening. According to my knowledge, spark does not perform anything before action (as it is lazy), then there are 503 stages in this case. I have to create a data frame and then convert into a tempView. After this using SQL, perform some operation of SQL. In my case, almost all setting is default.

Remaining sections of data processing are as follows:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("view1")
sqlContext.sql("select count(distinct(id)) from view1").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Optimizer with DFs and such differs to that of RDD processing. It can and does sometimes launch Stages ahead of an Action now where DFs are concerned. Zipped files, inferring schema and pivots, for example.

> In this case there is a case of wanting to infer schema. That is a
> slow process.
>
> 1. You can supply the schema which will then save time.
> 2. Or use a sampling percentage when inferring is specified; then this will be faster but you run the risk of not getting the overall correct schema.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more. What is possible solution to get rid of this (to save time) ?